# Pasar aplicación web React.js a móvil, Ionic o React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic, react-native, capacitor

desarrollé una aplicación web con React.JS, actualmente está funcional, pero ahora me piden pasarla a móvil, e investigando me encontré con que las mejores opciones son Ionic y React Native. Pero cuando veo como adaptarla entiendo que con React Native debo adaptar el código de React a Native, ajustando el HTML, el CSS y el enrutador, y tengo opciones como Expa.

Pero con Ionic no me queda claro, necesito cambiar los componentes a Ionic framework? Porque ví que con Ionic/capacitor se puede "envolver" la app y generar los APK/Ipa directamente desde el build de React, ¿es esto cierto? ¿Cuál es el truco?

Cabe destacar que la aplicación en React ya está completamente desarrollada en enfoque Mobile, es decir, en los estilos ya está manejando todo correcto para móvil utilizando sass. (tampoco sé si Sass sería también un problema)

Sé que es un poco amplia la pregunta, pero necesito guía.

Gracias.

Comment: Capacitor te permite empaquetar el código de la app web y generar las apps nativas. Idealmente no es necesario hacer ningún cambio en el código de la app web. Ionic es un framework ui así que no es requerido.

Comment: Tendras q hacerlo manualmente, no hay un programa.

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que si has desarrollado tu web en React lo hagas con React Native, toda la logica te va a servir lo único que vas a tener que adaptar es el CSS y los componentes, sobre todo trata la app web y la app móvil por separado será lo mejor para tener una adaptación 100%.

Comment: En este caso estuve revisando sobre React Native y me doy cuenta que está el tema de CSS que tengo que cambiar las propiedades, pero para los componentes como se actualizan? Cambiando el HTML por lo que indica React Native? Y las rutas y demás sigue igual?